# Exclude favicon in regex

Tags: regex, go

I have a site that uses states in the url, like

```
/alabama
/alaska
```

But the favicon is using the same path.

```
/favicon.ico
```

This is the route:

```
router.HandleFunc("/{[a-z]+\b*[favicon.ico]\b}", stateHandler).Methods("GET")
```

The favicon is not being excluded from the pattern.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps use `/[a-z]+$` https://regex101.com/r/0hR3gy/1

Comment: Seems far easier to me to just register [http.NotFoundHandler](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NotFoundHandler) under /favicon.ico before setting up stateHandler.

Comment: Without knowing what `router` is, it's hard to help you.

Comment: @meager your question doesnt have impact on the post, as the answer will be the same regardless of `router`. This should be reopened

Answer (score 1):

As stated by `Peter` that you can register [http.NotFoundHandler](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NotFoundHandler) for `/favicon.ico` route

```golang
router.HandleFunc("/favicon.ico", http.NotFoundHandler).Methods("GET")
```

You can also write middleware

```golang
// Middleware function, which will be called for each request
func FaviconMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if (!strings.Contains(r.URL.Path, "favicon.ico")) {
            http.NotFoundHandler()
        }
        else {
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)          
        }
    })
}
r.Use(FaviconMiddleware)
```